# Refactor methods into a Single Method by using typescript Generics

Tags: angular, typescript, generics

How do I refactor this using typescript generics? I have this 3 methods and I want these to be written down to just one method that accepts the TYPE T -  to eliminate repeated code.

```
 private initializeBlueComponentIframe() {
        const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(BlueComponent);
        this.dynamicIframeContent.clear();
        const dynamicComponent = <BlueComponent>this.dynamicIframeContent.createComponent(componentFactory).instance;
        dynamicComponent.facade = this;
        dynamicComponent.url = this.url;
        dynamicComponent.initialize();
    }

    private initializeBlackComponentIframe() {
        const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(BlackComponent);
        this.dynamicIframeContent.clear();
        const dynamicComponent = <BlackComponent>this.dynamicIframeContent.createComponent(componentFactory).instance;
        dynamicComponent.facade = this;
        dynamicComponent.url = this.url;
        dynamicComponent.initialize();    
    }

    private initializeGREENIframe() {
        const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(GreenComponent);
        this.dynamicIframeContent.clear();
        const dynamicComponent = <GreenComponent>this.dynamicIframeContent.createComponent(componentFactory).instance;
        dynamicComponent.facade = this;
        dynamicComponent.url = this.url;
        dynamicComponent.initialize(); 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the parameter and generic are the same there's no need for generic and you can just use the parameter.

```js
 type IframeComponents = BlueComponent | BlackComponent | Green Component


    private initializeIfame(component: IframeComponents) {
        const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);
        this.dynamicIframeContent.clear();
        const dynamicComponent = <component>this.dynamicIframeContent.createComponent(componentFactory).instance;
        dynamicComponent.facade = this;
        dynamicComponent.url = this.url;
        dynamicComponent.initialize();
    }
```

Then simply call the function with the proper component:

```
this.initializeIfame(BlueComponent)
```

However if you do need to denote what is being return you could use a generic like this:

```
    private initializeIfame<T>(component: IframeComponents): T {
        const componentFactory = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(component);
        this.dynamicIframeContent.clear();
        const dynamicComponent = <T>this.dynamicIframeContent.createComponent(componentFactory).instance;
        dynamicComponent.facade = this;
        dynamicComponent.url = this.url;
        dynamicComponent.initialize();
        // optional return
        return component;
    }
```

```
this.initializeIfame<BlueComponent>(BlueComponent)
```

Comment: I did create an interface named IIframe that implemented by black, blue, and green components and passed that as parameter. like initializeIframe(component: IIframe).

Same idea as this one